Generate SSG pages after the build in NextJS
Consider page home/[slug], slug is fetched from db on build time to generate SSG pages (home/1, home/2).
After the build a new entry (3) is added to db, it does server side rendering to show home/3 page. Is there a way to make the new id added in database to generate a SSG page?
